# No setter/field for name found on class for Firebase

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I have seen others ask this question but it seems to me that I have done all the things that are required and I'm still not getting it to work. I am getting the No setter/field for name found on class error. [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW2Ix.png)
I included a pic of what my database is. It is incredibly simple.

```
public class Restaurants {
private String name;

public Restaurants(){}

public Restaurants(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRestaurant()
{
    return name;
}
public void setRestaurant(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Restaurants" +
    "name" + name;
    }
}
```

I have my getter and setter here so in theory it should be working.

```
public class RestaurantSelectionList extends Fragment {

    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mRestReference = mRootRef.child("restaurants");

    List<String>listofrest = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView restaurantListView;
    ListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;


    public RestaurantSelectionList(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_selection_list_frag,container,false);
        restaurantListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);
        restaurantListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Restaurants>(getActivity(),Restaurants.class,R.layout.individual_restaurant_name,mRestReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Restaurants model, int position) {
                TextView restName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restname);
                restName.setText(model.getRestaurant());

                listofrest.add(position,model.getRestaurant());
            }
        };

        restaurantListView.setAdapter(restaurantListAdapter);

        restaurantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

This is the code that calls it. Please tell me what I am missing. This is going on 4 hours of looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your Model Class to:

```
public class Restaurants {

    private String name;

    public Restaurants(){}

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Restaurants" + "name" + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have seen that